# Сакраментальный вопрос "Как дела?"

Tags: этикет

Частенько после обмена приветствиями человек спрашивает: "Как дела?" Причем, вряд ли его интересует твой подробный рассказ о своих делах. Это своего рода форма вежливости. Но меня интересует: насколько вообще вежлив этот вопрос (не уместнее ли будет спросить "Как поживаете?" или вообще ничего подобного не спрашивать) и, главное, что полагается на этот вопрос отвечать?
У меня ощущение, что это самое "как дела?" вообще появилось в русском языке как калька с английского "how do you do" или "how are you". Но, если там это просто форма приветствия, не требующая ответа, то у нас это все-таки какой-никакой, а вопрос.
Кто что думает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что не всегда этот вопрос уместен. Только в общении с друзьями, знакомыми, т. е. людьми, равными вам по положению в обществе. Не будете же вы подобным образом приветствовать своего начальника. И зануд, начинающих в ответ подробным образом описывать свои дела, в последнее время, по моим наблюдениям, становится меньше. Я этот вопрос воспринимаю  как дань вежливости, не больше.

Answer (score 5):

С одной стороны, приветствие "Как дела" уместно не во всякой ситуации и имеет ограниченную область применения. С другой стороны, эту область можно отчасти расширить более вежливым "Здравствуйте. Как Ваши дела?"

По большому счету, это  даже не приветствие, а желание узнать настроение своего собеседника и его расположенность разговаривать с вами. Если вам ответили: "Прекрасно", то это означает, что настроение хорошее, разговор можно продолжить, вас готовы выслушать. Если же вы услышали: "Так себе", то лучше не надоедать человеку со своими рассказами и проблемами.

Comment: А по-моему, ответ "так себе" предполагает дальнейший разговор на тему "а что случилось?"

Comment: FuchoinKazuki, согласен с Вами.